# I want to make this prolog file a stand-alone EXE file

Tags: prolog, exe

I am new to prolog and I have written this code but I want to make this prolog file a stand-alone EXE file and I dont know how to go about it. I am using swi-prolog to consult the file. I need step by step tutorial on making this program executable using swi-prolog.I saved it as 'computer.pl' here is the code below.

```
main :- identify.

identify :-
  write('Welcome to Micro-Computer troubleshooting'),
  nl,
  write('Please do not forget to type all your answers with a period(.) in the end'),
  nl,
  retractall(known(_,_,_)),            % clear stored information
  diagnosis(X),
  nl,
  write('The problem is:  '),
  nl,
  writeListByLine(X).
identify :-
  nl,
  write('I can not identify the problem').

writeListByLine([]).
writeListByLine([H|T]) :-                 % write answers in newline
  write(H),
  nl,
  writeListByLine(T).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Audio Sound Card not detected %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

diagnosis(['damaged sound card']) :-
  problem('Audio Sound Card not detected'),
  nl,
  write('>> remove damaged sound card and replace with a new sound card <<'),
  nl,
  question_1('is the sound card working?').

diagnosis(['sound card not installed']) :-
 problem('Audio Sound Card not detected'),
 nl,
 write('>> install new sound card <<'),
 nl,
 question_2('can your computer detect the new sound card?').

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Audio Driver Warning %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

diagnosis(['driver conflict']) :-
  problem('Audio Driver Warning'),
  nl,
  write('>> uninstall previous audio drivers <<'),
  nl,
  question_1('is the audio driver working now?').

diagnosis(['incompatable audio driver']) :-
 problem('Audio Driver Warning'),
 nl,
 write('>> install the appropriate audio driver for your computer <<'),
 nl,
 question_2('is your computer still showing driver Warning?').

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Scratchy Sound %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

diagnosis(['signal interference']) :-
  problem('Scratchy Sound'),
  nl,
  write('>> stay away from radio frequency sources <<'),
  nl,
  question_1('is the sound working fine now?').

diagnosis(['bad speaker']) :-
  problem('Scratchy Sound'),
  nl,
  write(' >> connect a ear phone to the computer <<'),
  nl,
  question_2('is the ear phone giving scratchy sound also?').

diagnosis(['bad speaker']) :-
  problem('Scratchy Sound'),
  nl,
  write('>> replace speaker <<'),
  nl,
  question_3('it should be working fine now ?').

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Num lock stays off at startup %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

diagnosis(['num lock shut off in BIOS']) :-
  problem('Num lock stays off at startup'),
  nl,
  write('>> turn on num lock in BIOS <<'),
  nl,
  question_1('does num lock on at startup?').

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Invalid Drive Specification Error %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

diagnosis(['drive not yet formatted']) :-
  problem('Invalid Drive Specification Error'),
  nl,
  write('>> format your drive <<'),
  nl,
  question_1('does your drive shows the drive letter?').

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Mouse Pointer Jerks Onscreen %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

diagnosis(['mouse ball or rollers are dirty']) :-
  problem('Mouse Pointer Jerks Onscreen'),
  nl,
  write('>> clean mouse mechanism <<'),
  nl,
  question_1('does the mouse still jerks on onscreen?').

diagnosis(['damaged mouse']) :-
 problem('Mouse Pointer Jerks Onscreen'),
 nl,
 write('>> connect the mouse to another computer <<'),
 nl,
 write('>> replace mouse <<'),
 nl,
 question_2('does the mouse still jerks on onscreen?').

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% System Cant find my Hard Drive %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

diagnosis(['boot priority error']) :-
 problem('System Cant find my Hard Drive'),
 nl,
 write('>> set hard drive as the first booting device <<'),
 nl,
 question_1('does your hard drive now load at startup?').

diagnosis(['crashed hard drive']) :-
 problem('System Cant find my Hard drive'),
 nl,
 write('>> insert another hard drive to your computer,if the hard drive load at startup then previous hard drive has crashed <<'),
 nl,
 question_2('does your system recognize the hard drive?').

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Random shutdown when working on computer %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

diagnosis(['over heating']) :-
 problem('Random shutdown when working on computer'),
 question_1('does your computer get very hot when working?').

diagnosis(['dusty vent']) :-
 problem('Random shutdown when working on computer'),
 question_2('is their blockage or dust in the system vent?').

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% computer freezes randomly %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

diagnosis(['hard drive is full']) :-
 problem('computer freezes randomly'),
 question_1('is your hard drive full').

diagnosis(['system RAM is faulty']) :-
 problem('computer freezes randomly'),
 question_2('does your system shows blue-screen errors at startup?').

diagnosis(['bad hard drive']) :-
 problem('computer freezes randomly'),
 question_3('does your hard drive make loud noise?').

diagnosis(['bad hard drive']) :-
 problem('computer freezes randomly'),
 question_4('does your computer boot slowly?').

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Blue-screens %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

diagnosis(['Bad memory modules']) :-
 problem('Blue-screens'),
 nl,
 write('>> check memory with memtester and see if you get errors <<'),
 nl,
 write('>> if you do get errors and have more than one slots occupied <<'),
 nl,
 write('>> then test one by one and see if it works <<'),
 nl,
 question_1('did the test work?').

diagnosis(['corrupt drivers installed']) :-
 problem('Blue-screens'),
 nl,
 write('>> perform system restore to uninstall the corrupted drivers <<').

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Monitor is blank %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

diagnosis(['no power to monitor']) :-
 problem('Monitor is blank'),
 question_1('check if the monitor connected to power source?').

diagnosis(['monitor not connected to computer']) :-
 problem('Monitor is blank'),
 question_2('is the monitor connected to the CPU?').

diagnosis(['screen-saver enabled']) :-
 problem('Monitor is blank'),
 question_3('check if screen-saver is enabled').

diagnosis(['display card not connected']) :-
 problem('Monitor is blank'),
 question_4('is display card connected?').








%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% This is where the asking starts %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
problem(X):- menuask(problem,X,['Audio Sound Card not detected',
                'Audio Driver Warning', 'Scratchy Sound',
                'Num lock stays off at startup','Invalid Drive Specification Error',
              'Mouse Pointer Jerks Onscreen', 'System Cant find my Hard Drive', 'Random shutdown when working on computer',
               'computer freezes randomly', 'Blue-screens', 'Monitor is blank']).           % shows menu
question_1(X):- ask(question_1,X).
question_2(X):- ask(question_2,X).
question_3(X):- ask(question_3,X).
question_4(X):- ask(question_4,X).
question_5(X):- ask(question_5,X).
question_6(X):- ask(question_6,X).
question_7(X):- ask(question_7,X).
question_8(X):- ask(question_8,X).
question_9(X):- ask(question_9,X).
question_10(X):- ask(question_10,X).
question_11(X):- ask(question_11,X).
question_12(X):- ask(question_12,X).

% "ask" only deals with simple yes or no answers. a "yes" is the only
% yes value. any other response is considered a "no".

ask(Attribute,Value):-
  known(yes,Attribute,Value),       % succeed if we know its true
  !.                                % and dont look any further
ask(Attribute,Value):-
  known(_,Attribute,Value),         % fail if we know its false
  !, fail.

ask(Attribute,_):-
  (known(yes,Attribute,_)),           % fail if we know its some other value.
  !, fail.                          % the cut in clause #1 ensures that if
                                    % we get here the value is wrong.
ask(A,V):-
  write(A:V),                       % if we get here, we need to ask.
  write('? (yes or no): '),
  read(Y),                          % get the answer
  asserta(known(Y,A,V)),            % remember it so we dont ask again.
  Y = yes.                          % succeed or fail based on answer.

% "menuask" is like ask, only it gives the user a menu to to choose
% from rather than a yes on no answer.

menuask(Attribute,Value,_) :-
  known(yes,Attribute,Value),       % succeed if we know
  !.
menuask(Attribute,_,_) :-
  known(yes,Attribute,_),           % fail if its some other value
  !, fail.

menuask(Attribute,AskValue,Menu):-
  nl,write('What is the '),write(Attribute),write('?'),nl,
  display_menu(Menu),
  write('Enter the number of choice> '),
  read(Num),nl,
  pick_menu(Num,AnswerValue,Menu),
  asserta(known(yes,Attribute,AnswerValue)),
  AskValue = AnswerValue.           % succeed or fail based on answer

display_menu(Menu) :-
  disp_menu(1,Menu), !.             % make sure we fail on backtracking

disp_menu(_,[]).
disp_menu(N,[Item | Rest]) :-        % recursively write the head of
  write(N),write(' : '),write(Item),nl, % the list and disp_menu the tail
  NN is N + 1,
  disp_menu(NN,Rest).

pick_menu(N,Val,Menu) :-
  integer(N),                       % make sure they gave a number
  pic_menu(1,N,Val,Menu), !.        % start at one
  pick_menu(Val,Val,_).             % if they didn't enter a number, use
                                    % what they entered as the value

pic_menu(_,_,none_of_the_above,[]). % if we've exhausted the list
pic_menu(N,N, Item, [Item|_]).      % the counter matches the number
pic_menu(Ctr,N, Val, [_|Rest]) :-
  NextCtr is Ctr + 1,               % try the next one
  pic_menu(NextCtr, N, Val, Rest).
```

Comment: So is not a tutorials site. What have you tried so far to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 3):

As your code looks nicely portable on a quick reading, you can use GNU Prolog to generate an `.exe` file from it. Assuming the code is saved in a file named `foo.pl`, you can use GNU Prolog `gplc` command-line utility to generate your executable file:

```
$ gplc --no-top-level -o foo.exe foo.pl
```

But first you will need to add the following directives to your code at the top of the file:

```
:- initialization(main).
:- dynamic(known/3).
```

The `gplc` utility will report an error without the `dynamic/1` directive. Running `foo.exe` will print:

```
$ ./foo.exe
Welcome to Micro-Computer troubleshooting
Please do not forget to type all your answers with a period(.) in the end

What is the problem?
1 : Audio Sound Card not detected
2 : Audio Driver Warning
3 : Scratchy Sound
4 : Num lock stays off at startup
5 : Invalid Drive Specification Error
6 : Mouse Pointer Jerks Onscreen
7 : System Cant find my Hard Drive
8 : Random shutdown when working on computer
9 : computer freezes randomly
10 : Blue-screens
11 : Monitor is blank
Enter the number of choice>
```

P.S. GNU Prolog is one of the few available Prolog compilers that can generate a true `.exe` file that you can distribute to others without requiring them to also have GNU Prolog installed.

Comment: i will install GNU  Prolog now and do as you said. Thank you i really appreciate your help.i will let you know how it goes.

Comment: i have installed GNU Prolog and i have inserted does directives to my code but gplc command line opens and close by itself. i dont know if the problem is that am running on windows10.

Comment: I don't have access to Windows 10 but it seems that some dependency is missing, likely a supported C compiler called by `gplc` to generate native code on that operating-system.

Comment: please can you tell me on how to  make the program executable using swi-prolog.

Comment: @osca1 are you still looking for a solution using swi-prolog?