# making prolog program EXECUTABLE

Tags: prolog

I am working on a prolog project and i would like to make it executable.

How can I do this?

I am using swi-prolog

Comment: What Prolog system are you using? This is not a standardized aspect of Prolog, so the answer will depend on what you're using.

Comment: SWI-Prolog has [an FAQ entry](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/MakeExecutable.html) about this.

Comment: See also the following related question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147207/i-want-to-make-this-prolog-file-a-stand-alone-exe-file